# Is should the past form of shall?

Tags: modal-verbs

I am a non-native English speaker. I have been learning English for a few months. Some people say that **"should"** is the past form of **"shall"** but some people say that it is not true. I have asked this question because I was reading a novel and in the novel I found something which looks wrong to me.

**From the novel:**

> I managed to nod. I **should say** something. I just wasn't sure what to
>   say. He was waiting on me to speak. “I like them,” I blurted out
>   nervously.

**As per my opinion:**

> I managed to nod. I **should have** said something. I just wasn't sure
>   what to say. He was waiting on me to speak. “I like them,” I blurted
>   out nervously.

My question is that the writer should not have used **"should"** for
the past action. It should have replaced by **"should have"**.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with main clause *should* as a past tense form.  *Should have* sounds okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow her narrative in the novel (to me, that *I* sounds like a young lady), you can think like this:

> *I **should say** something.*
>   = She thought that it would be appropriate to say something.

That is, this thought came to her mind ***before*** the moment she thought she should say something.

Compare it with:

> *I **should have said** something.*
>   = She thought that it would have been appropriate if she had said something.

That is, at the time she thought it, saying something would be the act that she should already have done. In other words, that thought would come to her mind ***after*** the moment that she should have said it.

Comment: I agree with you. I also had the same point, but I think in that case the writer could show it (should say) specially (double quotation marks or single quotation marks), like a direct or indirect speech example. So readers could understand it better. Does it make sense?

Comment: No, the text is good as it is, without any quotation marks. Think of it as "future in the past". In that moment in the past, she was thinking into the future. In this case, it's a very near future, an immediate one.

Comment: Thanks. You made it clear. I appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that it's helpful. :-)

Comment: As an aside, it might be the best to understand "shall" and "should" separately. In indirect speech (present tense), we usually turn *shall* into *will*, *should*, or *can*, depending on the intended meaning. And if we need to backshift in reporting, usually *We shall/should ...* would be reported as *They said they would ....* Also, we can use *should* as the backshifted version of *should* too. For example, *I thought 'I should do it'.* would become *I thought I should do it.* No tense shifting needed.

Answer (score 3):

I found this entry in *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan.

> **519 should (2): obligation, deduction etc.**
>   **3 past use: I knew that I should ...; I was supposed to ...**
>   
>   *Should* is used unchanged in past indirect speech, if *should* was used in direct speech.
>       *I thought 'I **should** write to Jane.'* --> *I knew that I **should** write to Jane.*
>   In other cases, ***should + infinitive*** is not normally used to talk about the past. Instead, we can use for example *was/were supposed to* ... (see 572).
>       *It was going to be a long day. I **was supposed to** clean up all the stables, and then start on the garden.* (NOT *... <del>I should</del> clean up ...*)
>       *She **was supposed to** be in her office, but she wasn't.* (NOT *<del>She should be in her office, but she wasn't.</del>*)

Based on this entry (especially the last example), I believe that the other answer of mine is incorrect, but I couldn't delete it because it has already been accepted.

The main reason is that the narrative doesn't sound like something in past indirect speech. So, it should be rewritten as:

> *I **was supposed to** say something.*

I also believe that rewriting it with *should have said* is possible:

> *I **should have said** something.*

Answer (score 2):

Although should is technically the past of shall it is rarely, if ever, used in that manner.  The only time this would be an issue would be during reported speech.

Direct speech:  "Shall we go for a walk?"  Reported speech: John asked whether we should go for a walk.

However, the reported speech is more likely to be expressed: John suggested going for a walk.  Direct speech: "Shall I help you with that?"  Reported: John offered to help her with her assignment.

In other cases, should is used to express the opinion of the speaker as to what the right thing to do would be.  A sentence such as "I think you should get more exercise," means that the speaker's opinion is that getting more exercise is the right thing to do.